# AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_tag_name'

Tags: webdriver, attributeerror

AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_tag_name'
my code - github.com/eminsk/captcha

AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_tag_name'

Answer (score 2):

`find_element_by_*` and `find_elements_by_*` are now removed.

Refer:https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/a4995e2c096239b42c373f26498a6c9bb4f2b3e7/py/CHANGES

Use this instead:

```
findElement(By.TAG_NAME,"HTML Tag Name")
```

On top, you will have to do an import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium 4.3.0, they removed `find_element_by_*` and `find_elements_by_*`.

Refer: https://github.com/MetaProvide/talked/issues/49

> The syntax "find_element_by_ ... " throws an `AttributeError` with the latest version of Selenium, because that syntax is deprecated.
>
> `find_element_by_css_selector(` has to be replaced with `find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR`,
> `find_element_by_tag_name(` has to be replaced with `find_element(By.TAG_NAME`,